# Oracle apex get interactive grid row count

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

Inquiring if there is any way to get the row count of an interactive grid and save the value into an item.

I was trying other solutions from oracle forums but none worked for me.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use Javascript to get the total records:

```
var totalRec = apex.region("theIG").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model.getTotalRecords()
```

the you can safe the result in an application item:

```
apex.item( "P_ITEM" ).setValue( totalRec );
```

you can find more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/model.html#getTotalRecords)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can this also be applicable to interactive reports?

Comment: Oh I see, is there any way to get the row count of InteractiveReport?

Answer (score 0):

using classic report, assign igViewTimesheet as static ID to classic report

```
var iRows = $('#igViewTimesheet').length
```

using interactive report, assign igViewTimesheet as static ID to interactive report

```
var str = $('#igViewTimesheet .a-IRR-pagination-label').text();
var iRows = str.charAt(str.length-1);
```

using interactive grid, assign igViewTimesheet as static ID to interactive grid

```
var iRows = apex.region('igViewTimesheet').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews', 'grid').model.getTotalRecords();
```